# Should asking a broad "is [action] legal anywhere?" question preclude specific questions about the legality of that action in a specific country?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

Motivating example: [Is it legal to hack a hacker back (in the US)?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/58188/32651) was marked as a duplicate of
[Is there any country where hacking back is legal?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/57731/32651)

The former asks a specific question that can be answered in the negative with an explanation of why this action is not legal in the United States, with citations to the specific laws responsible for that being the case, as well as additional context.

The latter asks if it's legal in any country, with one answer noting that it's legal in some unspecified countries in Africa.

I have answered the former, and I don't believe my answer would be a good answer to the latter. My answer does not address whether there is any country where that *is* legal; rather, it explains why it is *not* legal in a specific country.

Answer (score 4):

Specific questions should only be marked as duplicates of broad survey questions *if* the specific question is already addressed in the existing answers to the broader question.

This is why Stack Exchange requires that a question have an upvoted or accepted answer (or be asked by the same user) in order to be used as a duplicate target: we should be pointing users to **answers**, not related questions without relevant answers.